# c like string inverse not working for input c like string with less than 5 chars

Tags: c++, string, inverse

Here is the function:

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
    char * endOfString = str ; 
    char temp ; 
    if(str)
    { 
         while(*endOfString)
         {
         ++endOfString;
         }
         --endOfString ; 
         while(str < endOfString)
         {
         temp = *str ; 
         *str++ = *endOfString ; 
         *endOfString-- = temp ;
         }
    }

}
```

and with this input :

```
int main()
{
    char cStrg[3] = {'a','b','c'} ;
    reverse(cStrg) 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

The output looks like ths: 
� % %. 
If I enter a bigger input, lets just say :
`char cStrg[6] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'} ;` the output looks like this : 
f e d c b a,
which is perfectly fine, does anybody know what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 3):

`char cStrg[3] = {'a','b','c'};` is not a null terminated string, as expected by your `reverse` function. You should replace it by `char cStrg[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0};` or `char* cStrg = "abc";`

Comment: thanks a lot. any clue why that used to work with bigger inputs even though I never added the termination ?

Comment: because of random luck with undefined behavior

Comment: Your function may be working if for example you declare your array like `char cStrg[3] = {'a', 'b'}`, since the compiler will automatically initialize the missing elements with 0. Also the function may work sometimes due to the fact that the memory can contain a zero byte after the location of your array.

Answer (score 0):

**C strings - it's sequence of characters which ending by `\0` character**. **All standard function in C working with that sort of string.** So, if you want to work with string in C you must specify it.

**Example:**

```
`char str1[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};` // it's just array of characters and that's it
`char str2[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c','\0'};` // it's valid C-string
```

If you forget to point `'\0'` at the end of array - you will not have "true" C-string. So if you try to work with `str1` as with string you will retrieve **UB**.

`char* str = "abc"; // that's like {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}; // '\0' character will be added automatically`